# jsPDF: How to use doc.text() to print strings in separate lines?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a loop that prints strings in a JSON object.

```
for (var i in list){
    doc.text(list[i]['id'] + '  ' + list[i]['name'], 10 ,10)
}
```

In the pdf file, all strings overlapped in the first line. I tried adding '\n' but it didn't work. How do I use doc.text() to print strings in separate lines?

Comment: Not sure, but according to the doc, create an array of string and call doc.text(yourArray,10,10). http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you're using takes the parameters (coordinates) x and y like so: `doc.text(text, x, y, flags)`. So to print the strings in seperate lines, you should add something to the y-component of the coordinate each time the loop runs. Example:

```
for (var i in list){
    doc.text(list[i]['id'] + '  ' + list[i]['name'], 10, 10 + 10*i)
}
```

Source: [jsPDF.text](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#text)

EDIT: As said in the comments, you could also just pass an array of the text you want to display like this:

```
var text = []
for (var i in list){
    text.push(list[i]['id'] + '  ' + list[i]['name'])
}
doc.text(text, 10, 10)
```

Comment: If this did it for you, please mark this as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)